# method details not showing while debugging with resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Since last time I closed my solution and opened it, I'm not able to see method details(definition, return type, parameter type) on mouse hover. Everything else looks fine(variables etc). Any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloaded the project and applied VS keyboard schemes.